# Overloaded function does not accept all possible arguments: what am I missing?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have this in `lazystr.py`:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import ParamSpec, overload


_P = ParamSpec("_P")


class LazyString: ...


@overload
def lazystr(func: Callable[_P, str], *args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> LazyString:
    ...

@overload
def lazystr(func: str, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> str:
    ...

def lazystr(func: Callable[_P, str] | str, *args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> LazyString | str:
    ...
```

I get this error when I run `mypy --strict --show-error-codes lazystr.py`:

```
lazystr.py:58: error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 2  [misc]
```

What am I missing in the signature of `lazystr` that Mypy is looking for?

I don't get any error when I run `pyright lazystr.py`.

I tested this with Mypy v0.982 and Pyright v1.1.276.

Comment: As a workaround, I annotated the implementation as `*args: Any, **kwargs: Any`, since Mypy will ignore the annotations on the implementation anyway.

Comment: I tried `_P.args | object`, which is obviously redundant but why not. Didn't work, but raises the question: what if you had not used `object` but say `int`? There doesn't appear to be a valid notation for `*args : _P.args | int`

Comment: Interestingly, you can also annotate `*args: Any, **kwargs: Any` on the 2nd signature and it will also pass `mypy`. I would like to understand the reasoning for this. Seems like a bug to me tbh. By annotating with `Any` instead of `object` we _broaden_ the possible types for the 2nd call, yet somehow now the implementation _is_ congruent with it?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg we do not broaden possible types with `Any`. `Any` is not simply "the widest type possible". It is more like "do whatever you want type", so for any type `T` both `T <: Any` and `Any <: T` hold at the same time. It is closer to "type: ignore" on every statement containing `Any`. This question is quite interesting, however. I'd disallow all arguments for 2nd overload (would be nice to see your implementation bare bones - are they used in fact? Looks like they shouldn't), and this [passes](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=a7ce0cfdb8e207c988a730a2f91168cf)

Comment: (You can safely assign `Any` to variable of type `int` or `object`, so it is definitely not just "the widest type")

Comment: This could also be an example where you want two separate methods instead of an overload.